# Release SQL Server Memory usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

How can release memory usage of sql server by command. my system have 16GB RAM, but when get huge query by sql server, memory usage become full. if I restart SQL Server service memory usage become free. but I want to release memory usage of sql server after each huge query execute.

Comment: [How to adjust memory usage by using configuration options in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321363)

Comment: Is it a problem that SQL-Server is using a lot of memory?

Comment: I use SSIS to convert data from OldDatabase to NewDatabase, when package1 execute, system memory usage become full and execute of package2 become very slow. but if I restart SQL Server service and realease sql server memory usage and then execute package2, this package run very fast.

Comment: Please see this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6691/how-to-free-sql-server-memory

Comment: I did set the "max sever memory" option, but somehow it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL Server is supposed to use all the memory.  If you want to reserve memory for other things set the max server memory setting in SQL Server so that it'll stop eating up all the memory.

Comment: I would always suggest to set a max memory, otherwise you can run in memory problems even on dedicated machines.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will always use as much as memory as he can gets. Even on a server which is designed just for SQL Server, you should define a max memory usage on the instance. Otherwise your windows can run in a memory pressure if you try to connect to the machine as admin.